# Latex Diagram with Squares and Arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm not sure if this is an acceptable kind of question, but figured I'd give it a shot.

I'm trying to replicate a basic diagram using LaTeX but I'm having trouble figuring out how to start.
[image],

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It is absolutely possible to draw such a diagram e.g. with Ti*k*Z but may I ask you what you've tried?

Comment: I used some tree  template I found on the internet, but no clue how to insert the graphs as in the picture

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Drawing the figure is not very difficult. But you are forcing anyone who is willing to answer your question to type up things from your screen shot. Don't you agree that this is a bit too much?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,fit,positioning,backgrounds,shadows}
\tikzset{pics/.cd,
Gauss graph/.style n args={4}{
code={
\draw[-latex] (0,-0.5) -- (0,2.5);
\draw[-latex] (-1,0) -- (3.65,0);
\draw[thick] plot[variable=\x,domain=-1:3.5,samples=51] ({\x},{#3*Gauss(\x,#1,#2)});
\node[anchor=south] at (1.5,0){#4};
}}}
\tikzset{cylinder end fill/.style={path picture={
\pgftransformshift{\centerpoint}%
\pgftransformrotate{\rotate}%  
\pgfpathmoveto{\beforetop}%
\pgfpatharc{90}{-270}{\xradius and \yradius}%
\pgfpathclose
\pgfsetfillcolor{#1}%
\pgfusepath{fill}}
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,
declare function={Gauss(\x,\y,\z)=exp(-(\x-\y)*(\x-\y)/\z);}]
% left Gauss
\pic[local bounding box=Gauss-1] at (0,0) {Gauss graph={1.25}{1}{1.2}{$complicated$}};
\node[above=6mm of Gauss-1,anchor=north,align=center] (lab1) {Marmot view\\ (default view)};
\node[ellipse,draw,fill=gray!20,above=2cm of Gauss-1](public) {Public information};
% right Gauss
\pic[local bounding box=Gauss-2] at (9,0) {Gauss graph={1.25}{1}{1.5}{$complicated$}};
\node[above=6mm of Gauss-2,anchor=north,align=center] (lab2) {PM views};
\node[ellipse,draw,fill=gray!20,above=2cm of Gauss-2] (private) {Private information};
% fits
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\node[ellipse,draw,fill=gray!20,inner ysep=-3pt,fit=(Gauss-1) (lab1)](fit1){};
\node[ellipse,draw,fill=gray!20,inner ysep=-3pt,fit=(Gauss-2) (lab2)](fit2){};
\end{scope}
\node[draw,fit=(public) (private) (fit1) (fit2),inner ysep=9mm](upper fit){};
\node[below right=1pt of upper fit.north west,anchor=north west] {View
generation};
% lower Guss
\pic[local bounding box=Gauss-3] at ([yshift=-7.2cm,xshift=-1.35cm]upper fit.south) {Gauss
graph={1.25}{1.2}{2}{$complicated$}};
\node[above=6mm of Gauss-3,anchor=north,align=center] (lab3) {Combined views};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\node[ellipse,draw,fill=gray!20,inner ysep=-3pt,fit=(Gauss-3) (lab3)](fit3){};
\end{scope}
\node [draw,drop shadow,
  shape=cylinder,
  aspect=0.45,
  minimum height=3cm,
  minimum width=1cm,
  cylinder end fill=blue,
  left color=blue!30,
  right color=black,
  middle color=blue!80,
  shading angle=20,
  align=center,
  text=white,below=5mm of fit3]  (cylinder2) {Portfolio\\ optimizer};
% second frame
\node[draw,fit=(upper fit.west |-fit3.center) (upper fit.east |-fit3.center)
(fit3) (cylinder2.center),inner ysep=9mm,inner xsep=0pt](lower fit){};
\node[below right=1pt of lower fit.north west,anchor=north west] {Portolio
optimization};
% 
\node[ellipse,draw,fill=gray!20,below=3mm of lower fit,align=center](rel) {Relatively \\};
%
\draw (fit1.south) -- ++ (0,-3mm) -| (fit2.south) coordinate[pos=0.25] (aux);
\path (upper fit.south) -- (lower fit.north)
node [midway,draw,drop shadow,
  shape=cylinder,
  aspect=0.45,
  minimum height=3cm,
  minimum width=1cm,
  cylinder end fill=blue,
  left color=blue!30,
  right color=black,
  middle color=blue!80,
  shading angle=20,
  align=center,
  text=white]  (cylinder1) {Black--Littermann\\ model};
\draw[-latex] (aux -| cylinder1.north) -- (cylinder1.north);
\draw[-latex] (cylinder1) -- (fit3);
\draw[-latex] (fit3) -- (cylinder2);
\draw[-latex] (cylinder2) -- (rel);
\draw[-latex] (public) -- (fit1);
\draw[-latex] (private) -- (fit2);
\draw[-latex] (public) -- (fit2);
\node[cloud,draw,drop shadow,fill=white,align=center,anchor=west] at
([xshift=-3mm]cylinder1.east)
{Systematic \\ blah blah};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]